# Opening the SaveDialog intermittently crashes application

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Good morning,

I have researched this to no end and have tried several solutions with no success. This anomaly happens maybe 1 in 4 attempts to save in testing. When the save button is clicked, the SaveDialog will start to appear, freeze for a second and shut down the application. I have tried [StaThread], but it did not help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance. My code is below..

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
       try

        {

            using (SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                SFD.FileName = textBox11.Text.ToString();
                if (SFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)app.ActiveSheet;
                    ws.Name = textBox11.Text.ToString();
                    app.Visible = false;

                    int i = 2;
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in lstLocal.Items)

                    wb.SaveAs(SFD.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    wb.Close();
                    app.Quit();
                    wb = null;
                    app = null;

                    MessageBox.Show("File has been saved!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Comment: Is there some reason the ‘catch” statement is NOT catching the Exception? I would think the exceptions message would be helpful.

Comment: It's not catching it.

Comment: I do not think the problem is with the SFD… I am guessing it is something else. Change the "catch" line to `catch (Exception ex)`, then change the `MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);` this should show the error the exception is throwing.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that in the beginning and it refuses to catch the error. Just tried it again with the same results. Application just closes. I just checked Task Manager to see if the Excel app was actually closing on a previous file save, and it is not always closing even with the app.Quit(); Not sure if that can be an issue.

Comment: You may want to put the excel closing code in the `finally` portion of the `try/catch` to prevent multiple instances of excel. In addition,  When the program closes, do you see the “File has been saved” dialog? If not, then something else is going on and you will need to trace the code. It seems odd that the code would crash and not throw an exception here. Can you show the updated “catch” and “ex.Message” line?

Comment: Here is the updated catch  -
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                
            }

Comment: I will try moving the closing to finally to see if that helps.

Comment: As I stated, if you do not see the “File has been saved!” dialog AND you do not get an exception, then the code is crashing (somehow) and you will need to trace/step through it line by line.

Comment: Makes sense. I do see the the initial Open FileDialog (for just a second), then it and the application closes. But it never gets to the actual save before it crashes.

Comment: At this point I have just eliminated the dialog aspect of the save. It now opens Excel directly for edit and save purposes. I will have to go back and review/re-write the code from scratch to try and reach a conclusion. Thank you John for yor input and help.

Comment: I'm leary of the `foreach` in the code you 've posted. What do you expect this to do? And you don't have any brackets `{}` to indicate what should be affected. Won't this try to execute `saveAs` multiple times? That could be causing a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closure on this, it turned out to be an anomaly with my developing rig. I have since had to wipe it and re-install Win10/vS2017 for other reasons and the problem no longer exists. Compiled app on new install no longer has this issue on the developing rig or any others. Strange~  Thank you for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Next time run SysInternals' Autoruns.  It lets you selectively disable the shell extensions one by one, helps you find the one that crashes the dialog.  You might still need it, non-zero odds that you'll add the bad one back.